# Is there a way to hide the IDLE when running a tkinter application?

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

Is there a way to hide the IDLE (or not making it run at all), with a command, when launching a `tkinter` application, without having to build the application?

Answer (score 0):

Execute it directly from the command line with `python script.py`.